# What is the bigger cylindrical part found at the end of USB cables but also some laptop PSU cables?

Tags: usb, power-supply, cable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is that cylinder on cables?](https://superuser.com/questions/217772/what-is-that-cylinder-on-cables)

What's this part?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a [Ferrite Bead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead).

They're used to reduce and dissipate high frequency noise.

To prevent it from moving on the cable, it is overmoulded with plastic.

Functionally, it is a dissipative low-pass filter. It's basically an inductor with very high reluctance, so the magnetic field which it forms get dissipated as heat, rather than reflected back on the cable.

Comment: Why is high frequency noise a problem on a laptop power cable?

Comment: @jwg - Because laptops are excellent **sources** of it! It's actually more to prevent the laptop radiating electromagnetic noise then receiving it.

Answer (score 6):

It could be a [recording device disguised as a USB cable](http://www.spydevelopment.com/transmitter-disguised-usb-cable-du75.html).

Answer (score 2):

The device in your picture is most likely a ferrite ring and is used to reduce RF interference. You'll also see them on a lot of video cables.

You can also buy them as a separate item

Have a look [here](http://www.ce-mag.com/archive/02/11/may.html)