# What is the use of this joint in laptop charger?

Tags: laptop

We can see the first picture in this image they are making of this joint in laptop charger as **useless.**.

[image]

What is the use of this joint in laptop charger?

Comment: They are not saying it is "useless" only that you don't know what its purpose is. From personal experience they most definitely are not useless, but their use is highly situational and requires some in depth knowledge of the device they are attached to.

Comment: It's not that nobody knows their purpose either – even googling _"thing on cables"_ provides an answer (which is how I also found https://superuser.com/questions/217772/what-is-that-cylinder-on-cables).

Comment: For reference, the holes in the shoes are to allow air in. The stud on a jeans pocket can have a keyring attached, if only loosely. They're are likely more decorative now.

Comment: The stud on jeans are rivets. They are (partly) used for decoration these days, but they are actually meant to provide extra strength at points that are likely to see more than normal wear or tear. Historically you may have had a tool or something in that pocket which could have twisted or broken the stitching. The rivet gives a strong reinforced (metal) point that isn't going to be easily damaged.

Comment: That meme was made by someone with little comprehension of the world around them & a distinctly cavalier attitude towards grammar, syntax and punctuation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

That block is a [ferrite/ferrous bead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead), used to reduce the effect of electronic noise generated by the charger. It only wraps around the cable, but isn't actually a joint.