# Static Clicking Noise Coming From Earbuds When the Wireless Mouse's Receiver Is Plugged into the USB Port on the Same Side as the Headphone Jack

Tags: usb, audio, hardware-failure

My laptop has a USB port on both sides and on the left side there is also a headphone jack. When I plug in my wireless mouse's receiver to the port on the left side, I hear a slight static noise coming from my headphones (earbuds, in-ear). When I put my hand on the laptop, between the keyboard and the headphone jack, the noise seems to be abating.

I must add that I always hear a static white noise coming from my headphones unless I set volume to 0% whether something is playing or not. Though, this noise is different as it resembles a continuous clicking. I don't hear the clicking when I plug the mouse's receiver into the USB port on the right.

What do you think is the problem? How would I go about fixing it?

[Check out the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ98I.jpg)

Comment: This is interference. Do your headphones have a ferrite bead/choke on the wire? Looks a bit like the cylinder in the image on this question https://superuser.com/questions/217772/what-is-that-cylinder-on-cables/217978#217978

Comment: @spikey_richie I added a photo of the cable to the post.

Comment: Try what happend if you wrap the first 5-10 cm of the headphone cable next to the PC in aluminum foil (or use a shielded head-phone cable).

Comment: So to help fill in @spikey_richie answer, this problem exists because of crappy shielding.  The components your are using were not well made.  The ferrite bead/choke is to help manage the shielding for the headphones.

Comment: For a permanent solution, look on your favourite online retailer for "clip-on ferrite choke" and find one with a small aperture to accommodate your cable. You want it to be a snug fit.